# for example "party:パーティー",how to type "ー"

Tags: discussion, writing

"party:パーティー",how to type "ー" in the computer

Comment: For all of the Japanese input tools I can think of, just a "-" produces the "ー", but I would think that'd be the first thing to try, so maybe you're using some tool I'm not aware of. What tool are you using to input Japanese?

Comment: わかりました、ありかとございます

Comment: You should be able to type `pa-thi-` to get `パーティー`.

Answer (score 4):

For all IMEs I'm aware of, typing a "-" results in a "ー".

If you're using the Windows IME, there are various tips on [this site](http://nihonshock.com/2010/04/12-japanese-ime-tips/) which you might be interested in.